# extract downloaded url filename

Tags: php, http

i am trying to figure out how to get the actual file name from the downloaded url.here is the download url .please note that this url is direct there is no redirect.

```
  http://xyzjsjwekeke.com/download/314543&r=515
```

when i click on this url a file starts downloading whose name is something very different like

```
   how_to_prepare_for_interview.pdf
```

but in download url theere is nothing like that .

i tried base extraxt but it gives output as last words after slash of url given

```
 $filename = array_shift(explode('?', basename($url)));
 echo $filename;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here - do you want to know how to set a file name when sending a download to the browser?

Comment: @Pekka i want to extract the actual file name so that i can store that name in my database but the file name like 314543&r=515 is of no use i want to store actual file name in above case how_to_prepare_for_interview.pdf

Comment: @Payal Malhotra: If you want that, I wonder what made you choosing `basename` and `explode` and `array_shift`? By best intentions I can not imagine how that *ever* would make sense. Do you know what those functions are for?

Comment: @hakre yes it will give me the last name of url

Comment: @PayalMalhotra `basename` is simply a string manipulation function. It won't access the URL so it can't give you anything as output that you didn't put into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get a file name from the url that does not have the file name in the first place.

From your URL

```
http://xyzjsjwekeke.com/download/314543&r=515
                                           ^----- Probably ID to the file
```

It probably takes the ID from the url and get the real from a storage system eg. MySQL, CDN etc) send sends its back via :

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$realName);
```

The way to get such a file name is directly from the HTTP headers. get the header information using Headers `get_headers` and extract the file name

Example

```
$headers = get_headers("http://xyzjsjwekeke.com/download/314543&r=515p",true);
$headers = array_combine(array_map("strtolower",array_keys($headers)),$headers);


$fileName = isset($headers['content-disposition']) ? strstr($headers['content-disposition'], "=") : null ;
$fileName = trim($fileName,"=\"'");

var_dump($fileName);
```

Comment: Please don't grow new help vampires on the site. If you think that *is* the issue, you could leave a duplicate link, however even that might feed the trolls.

Comment: @baba no output nothing is coming

Comment: @PayalMalhotra Mind the capitalization of `$file**N**ame` when echoing. It is different between your original code and this answer.

Comment: @Boann yeah first did the same mistake but after that corrected but no output

Comment: @PayalMalhotra sorry .... this is the best i can do .... see http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ to know the meaning of help vampires in hakre comments